Can't seem to centre page on mobile browser load up, automatically corrects itself to where I want it after scroll. html/css related
How the website loads on mobile
After a scroll the sections jumps to the desired loading location
So, I'm trying to centre a section with a heading, paragraph & button on a welcome page. My code successfully works for a computer browser but when i load it up on a mobile browser i run into the following issue;

The centred section is much lower than the centre, and when i scroll using my finger it automatically springs to life and jumps to the expected centre position. This is tatty looking in my opinion, I have seen multiple websites with working examples of what I aim to achieve but for the life of me I just can't figure it out.

Please see a very simplifed version of code below;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p></p>
        <button></button>
    </section>
</body>
</html>

html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
body{
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
section{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

I have searched the web for a potiental fix for this before but ended up dodging it instead. I'm back again because I really like landing pages or sections that are the same height & width as the screen size. This could be a simple case of not searching using the correct terminolgy but... I have searched for hours again this time again.
Any pointers to help or even the solution would be greatly appreciated.
TIA

There is probably no need of so many rules & selectors.
Here is a basic grid layout example for that little content:


html {
  display: grid;
  place-content:safe center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100svh;/* Small Viewport Units  for mobile */
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

body {
 /* margin: auto; *//* instead place-content:safe center;  if you prefer */
}

section {
  text-align: center;  /* texts need to be centered too ? */
}
<section>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <button>button</button>
</section>



About the min-height:100svh; commented in the snippet, take a look and explanations at https://css-tricks.com/the-large-small-and-dynamic-viewports/

Thank you for your swift reply, unfortunately the issue remains. This may be an issue caused by the way the browser loads?

I have updated this post with pictures of the problem

For the mobiles, height (min-height) should be 100dvh or 100svh to not take the whole screen'height into account, but only the part of the screen left to display the browser's view ;) Did you use those values and just what i proposed ? If you have other CSS files loaded , it can overwrite this part, and indeed, we have no clue about it ;) here is the code inside a pen you should be able to test right into your browser : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/xxoLzbq If it still goes wrong, Can you tell which browser is the bad one :)

For anyone struggling with this issue also. Here is where i found the answer to the issue  CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser
& here is the piece of code that fixed the issue;
min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
